# HTML 5 audio, video is not working Safari 5.1 WinXP

Tags: html, audio, video, safari, windows-xp

I am using safari 5.1 version browser. Refer the screen shot about my safari.[image: About Safari]

I am executing the following audio tag as html file, the audio is not playing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Multi-Source Audio Player</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <audio controls>
            <source src="data/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="data/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

And also I test the audio with live [sample](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all) w3school, its also no playing.

Please suggest how can I play HTML5 audio on safari 5.1.

Comment: I checked Network, console by inspect element, no service called and no error received.

Comment: side note: Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7 works fine. Did you install OGG codec on your Windows XP / did you install iTunes ?

Comment: Not installed OGG codec and iTunes.

Comment: Then you should re-order 2 sources. MP3 goes first.

Comment: I tried with reorder the sources. Still not playing. And also tried with attributes "autoplay". In chrome 24 it is playing good. Is need to upgrade safari for higher version?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have QuickTime installed? Safari needs QuickTime to play HTML5 audio and video. Daft I know but that's how it is.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will install QuickTime and test the audio.