# No sound of audio in Safari(Window OS)

Tags: php, jquery, html, safari

**Safari Version for Window 8.1**

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    </head>

    <body>

        <audio id="player" autoplay>            
        </audio>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#player").html("<source src='file path' type='audio/mp3'>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine in Chrome and not in Safari.

I already tried to add play() method and load method. But safari don't recognize these methods. It gives undefined error message

```
$("#player").load(); //Not working. Undefined error message coming.
$("#player").play(); //Not working. Undefined error message coming.
```

Already checked below links.

[Safari with audio tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804028/safari-with-audio-tag-not-working)

## Update - 1

Even below code is not working in Safari in Window OS. No sound

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head> 
    <body>      
        <audio autoplay src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update - 2**

below code is not working in Safari in Window OS. No sound

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head> 
    <body>      
        <audio autoplay>
            <source 
                 src='https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3' 
                 type='audio/mpeg'>
            </source>
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First try it without JS, using a SRC attribute but instead like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773322/4299358

Comment: Please check Updates

Comment: Safari's now on version 12. What are you doing with 5 still installed?

Comment: I am working in window 8.1. Is this version available for window OS?

Comment: Apple stopped providing Safari for Windows seven years ago. Why on earth are you using it?

Comment: Safari 5 for Windows... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433192/html-5-audio-video-is-not-working-safari-5-1-winxp indicates a QuickTime installation is needed. Also try an example only using HTTP, not HTTPS.